# Regex-base causes package to indirectly depends on multiple versions of the same package

Tags: haskell, cabal

I have a cabal file that calls for both `regex-posix-0.95.2` and `mtl-2.1.2`.  Somehow my system built `regex-base-0.93.2` against a much older version of the MTL, and in spite of my best efforts to get cabal to try again with the new version (including building a all the dependencies in a cabal sandbox) I cannot get cabal to let go of this bad version of regex-base.

What do I need to do to get cabal to build, install and use a new copy of `regex-base` useing the up-to-date version of the `mtl` package?

Comment: It seems there are some libraries already installed messing things up. Did you try the --reinstall flag when installing with cabal?

Comment: In a cabal sandbox, `cabal install --reinstall --force-reinstalls mtl` should install the latest version of mtl.